# Problems processing JPEGs using the inception model in Windows TensorFlow "Not a JPEG file"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've currently come across some bumps in the road while retraining my Inception model, I had previously made an image classifier via an Ubuntu Virtual Machine using VMWare but have chosen to switch to Windows in order to get GPU support, as my machine runs Windows.

Everything seems to be running fine, with the right CUDA and cuDNN files and libraries installed and the Hello TensorFlow test program running with no problems however when I try and run the Image Classifier program it throws me this error message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\9k= (2).jpg_inception_v3.txt
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\9k= (3).jpg_inception_v3.txt
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\9k= (4).jpg_inception_v3.txt
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\D+TFyaNUKZ5ZgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==.jpg_inception_v3.txt
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 9169
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1 = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_DecodeJPGInput_0)]]
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_DecodeJpeg_1", tensor_type=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 370, in create_bottleneck_file
    resized_input_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 305, in run_bottleneck_on_image
    {image_data_tensor: image_data})
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 9169
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1 = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_DecodeJPGInput_0)]]
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_DecodeJpeg_1", tensor_type=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'DecodeJpeg_1', defined at:
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1009, in main
    model_info['input_std'])
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 955, in add_jpeg_decoding
    decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpeg_data, channels=input_depth)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_image_ops.py", line 311, in decode_jpeg
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 9169
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1 = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_DecodeJPGInput_0)]]
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_DecodeJpeg_1", tensor_type=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1140, in main
    f.write('\n'.join(image_lists.keys()) + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1207, in __exit__
    exec_type, exec_value, exec_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3517, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1025, in main
    bottleneck_tensor, FLAGS.architecture)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 476, in cache_bottlenecks
    resized_input_tensor, bottleneck_tensor, architecture)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 418, in get_or_create_bottleneck
    bottleneck_tensor)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 373, in create_bottleneck_file
    str(e)))
RuntimeError: Error during processing file frogz\toad\D+TFyaNUKZ5ZgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==.jpg (Invalid JPEG data, size 9169
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1 = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_DecodeJPGInput_0)]]
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_DecodeJpeg_1", tensor_type=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'DecodeJpeg_1', defined at:
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1009, in main
    model_info['input_std'])
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 955, in add_jpeg_decoding
    decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpeg_data, channels=input_depth)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_image_ops.py", line 311, in decode_jpeg
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 9169
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1 = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_DecodeJPGInput_0)]]
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_DecodeJpeg_1", tensor_type=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
)
```

The training for the model then stops running and needs to be started again. I've searched online and it's known to be thrown when a PNG file is saved as a JPEG as shown by the line ***Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50*** which seems to be done quite frequently on Google Images. Is there any way to go about ignoring these files instead? It may be worth noting the model didn't halt the program with the same image set previously when ran on the Linux Virtual Machine.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Oliver

Comment: You seem to have hit the nail on the head there, cheers for that the inception model is now running.

Comment: One more thing however, the model now when detecting I assume an incorrectly labelled JPEG from the internet throws the error "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50" as seen below:

Comment: INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\9k= (3).jpg_inception_v3.txt
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\9k= (4).jpg_inception_v3.txt
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks\toad\D+TFyaNUKZ5ZgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==.jpg_inception_v3.txt

Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50

Comment: I don't know anything about that error. Perhaps just change your question and put those details in it, because command-line typo not really an interesting question (usually you should not make such an edit and change your question radically, but as no-one has answered properly so far, it should be OK this time)

Comment: When running the Inception model in the Linux Virtual Machine with the same image set it didn't seem to have this problem, would you know why this change in detection would happen? The model then stops training after the error is given. Thanks

Comment: No worries, and cheers will do